# Freemarker format BigDecimal to German Locale not working properly

Tags: formatting, freemarker, bigdecimal

[Following](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html) the documentation of FreeMarker :

[image]

Using :

```
<#setting number_format="0.##">
<#setting locale="hu">
German people write: ${12345678}
```

Should output as shown in picture but instead what i get is the below :

For input `new BigDecimal(4436372342.10)` => `4 436 372 342,10`

which doesn't have `.` but instead has  spaces .

Why that happens ?

Comment: ISTM that `locale="hu"` sets a Hungarian locale, not a German one. Try `locale="de_DE"` instead.

Comment: In other words: there is obviously an error in the FreeMarker documentation.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis ThNk you i will try it as soon as possible, please feel free to post it as an answer i will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a documentation error.

```
locale="hu"
```

sets a Hungarian locale. Its thousands separator is `' '`.

To set a German locale, try

```
locale="de_DE"
```

instead. That has `'.'` as thousands separator.

Comment: One more think in case you know , let's say i want the other numbers to have other formats ... can i apply like the German Format to only one number using a method or something like `?string("...pattern here")`

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS: Sorry, I don't know. Would be a nice new question.