# Freemarker format BigDecimal to German Locale using inline method

Tags: double, freemarker, bigdecimal, formatter

As a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518965/freemarker-format-bigdecimal-to-german-locale-not-working-properly) question , i want to ask the following :

I want to add the **German Format** to a number but not apply it to whole document like using :

```
<#setting number_format="0.##">
<#setting locale="de_DE">
German people write: ${12345678}
```

Is there something like ... ?

```
${numericalValue?locale("de_DE")}
```

Or i should open a feature request for it on free marker github repository ?

Comment: What's the use case for that?

Comment: @I just have many numbers in a template whivh need a formt of different Locale. Let's say 30 different locales.

Comment: I'm asking because I'm curious if it's an extreme use case or not. If it is extreme, then I think it's acceptable if you just call `#setting` before printing each number, or if you invest into a custom number format.

Comment: @ddekany It's a little bit of extreme and pretty repetitive for us adding all thr time the #setting

Comment: Depending on how much is it a problem, you can write some `#macro` like `<@loc 'de_DE'>${...}</@>`, or a custom number format like in `${someNumber?string('@loc:de_DE')}`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature out of the box. Though anything is possible with custom formats (see https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html).